# How to fix Mariadb Galera cluster error "Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds"

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, galera

I am getting following error on one of my node in Galera cluster and after the error, this node goes shutdown and eventually out from the Galera cluster. Someone please help to fix this.

```
Mutex LOCK_SYS created /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/mariadb-10.5.8/storage/innobase/lock/lock0lock.cc:461, lock var 2
[ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Semaphore wait has lasted > 600 seconds. We intentionally crash the server because it appears to be hung.
```